# Can we send whatsapp messeges without opening browser using pywhatkit?

Tags: whatsapp

I am trying to send what'sapp messages using pywhatkit library but it opens [web.whatsapp.com](http://web.whatsapp.com) and then sends the message I want to send it without opening [web.whatsapp.com](http://web.whatsapp.com) .Please help

Answer (score 0):

Not yet! `pywhatkit` library calls the browser behind the scenes to send a message with:

```py
import webbrowser as web

def sendWhatmsg( ... ):
    ...
    ...

    web.open('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone='+phone_no+'&text='+parsedMessage)
```